# trying to get others facebook page insights using Graph Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Hi I am trying to get some random facebook page insights using graph api or explorer. Initially when i try to get insights using this below url.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/198358615428/insights/page_fans_country
```

The above one is giving response for three days but when i try to get response for this for page_fans nothing was coming. may i know where i am doing wrong or is there any limitations on requests or others facebook page insights.

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/198358615428/insights/page_fans
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Venkat,

you need to have Admin Rights to get page_fans for any page as only Admin Access Token can return you that result. What you're doing in Graph Explorer is using your Access Token to view insights so only limited fields are visible to you

The Insights that you're viewing is actually Public Data, that can be fetched for any page, but if you're admin then you would be viewing different data which is private to the admin users only. (only data you see in insights is the public data, that can only be viewed for any page)

Docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights/

Answer (score -1):

For reading certain insights, user or page access token with read_insights permission is required.